# How to create a add-remove multiple items selection window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a requirement to integrate a selection box in a web application, similar to the image shown below. Is there any js/jquery libraries out there to generate this kind of window. Help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found these, Try them out:

http://www.jdxyw.com/?p=678

http://lovewithbug.com/technology/jquery/move-list-box-items-from-left-to-right-using-jquery/